# Four momentum squared and collisions

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, metric-tensor, vectors

So, I am not asking is the square of four-momentum of a particle an invariant to Lorentz trasnformations, but rather,is it invariant in dynamic situations? It seems to me that this also has to hold. So, is four-momentum squared same before and after collision, not the total, but for one particle in that collision?

Comment: four-momentum squared Is always c square

Comment: Isnt it c squared times the mass squared with a minus in front?

Comment: I don’t think so $P_{\mu }\cdot P^{\mu }=c^{2}$

Comment: The sign depends on your convention for writing 4-vectors or for forming scalar products. Obviously the convention used by particle physicists is superior in every way to that used by cosmologists. Obviously.

Comment: I am not asking about the sign

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that you and @Eli are in violent agreement about the sign ... once you account for conventions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the particle has neither

- Changed kind (as happens in, for example, in charged-current weak scattering)
- Gotten excited (which can happen to atoms, nuclei, and hadrons; though in some cases this would be written as a change of type as in a proton turning into a Delta, for instance)

then the mass is the same.

But ... in a lot of ways what I wrote is a tautology. If a particle stays the same then it stays the same.

Comment: So square of four momentum is constant for a particle given that its mass stays the same?

Comment: The square of the four momentum *is* the mass (up to uninteresting constants). Of course the change or don't change together.

Comment: I am just surprised i was solving compton scattering and somewher squared four momentum of an electron only to find out its equal to its mass!! I was puzzled....

Comment: Ah. Either your resource has done you a disservice my not making that connection clear or you didn't notice the importance at first. But either way you have it now.